# Клик по dropdown изменяет названия всех button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, bootstrap

В примере кода - меню, с использованием **Bootstrap**.

4 кнопки стоят в линию, выбор типа визы, выбор страны, выбор даты и кнопка отправить.

При клике по `dropdown`  элементу, и выборе одного пункта из его списка - должно поменяться название `dropdown` элемента на выбранное, но меняются названия не одного, а сразу всех `dropdown` элементов и одной кнопки.

Почему так происходит?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="type" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            Тип
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="type">
        <li><a href="#" data-value="action">Волонтерская</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="another action">Туристическая</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="something else here">Бизнес</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="country" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            Страна
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="country">
        <li><a href="#" data-value="action">Россия</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="another action">Албания</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="something else here">Алжир</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="btn-group">
      <input id="meeting1" type="date" value="2011-01-13" class="btn btn-info " />
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Подобрать</button>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/asc.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
      $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
      $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

parents('...') - находит всех родителей, удовлетворяющих условию. У Вас их 2, причем во внешнем содержатся все ваши кнопки. Либо уберите у внешнего div-а класс group-btn (это, кстати, и логике немного противоречит), либо конкретизируйте поиск элемента, что-то типа:

```
  $(this).closest(".btn-group").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
```

аналогично для первой строчки.

Comment: Вместо вложенных $($($( можно воспользоваться методом closest - он делает как раз то что вы пытались сделать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, благодарю. Правильно исправил?

Comment: Да, правильно..